# Cannot get the correct index of first cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

trying to access a `uilabel` from `cellForItemAtIndexPath` in didSelectItemAtIndexPath but couldn't get the first cell. here is my code

in **`cellForItemAtIndexPath`**

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
UILabel *featureName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, cell.frame.size.width-10, cell.frame.size.height-10)];
    featureName.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell addSubview:featureName];
```

in **`didSelectItemAtIndexPath`**

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UILabel *featureName = [cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
featureName.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

can get `label.tag` from all the cells but not the first one. And Application crashes when tap on first cell.

Comment: please show crash output from console

Comment: @VixHunk Just to be clear 0 is a valid value https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag?language=objc - the reason it was probably crashing is that its returning another view when you supply the value 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexPath.row` is 0 for the first row, but 0 is not a valid tag.
I think you should only use non-zero values.

Try i.e.

```
featureName.tag = indexPath.row + 1;

...

UILabel *featureName = [cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row+1];
```

Comment: Awesome, Worked Perfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: @VixHunk Just to be clear 0 is a valid value https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag?language=objc - the reason it was probably crashing is that its returning another view when you supply the value 0

Answer (score 0):

**cellForItemAtIndexPath**

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
UILabel *featureName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, cell.frame.size.width-10, cell.frame.size.height-10)];
    featureName.tag = indexPath.row + 1;
    [cell addSubview:featureName];
```

**in didSelectItemAtIndexPath**

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UILabel *featureName = [cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row + 1 ];
featureName.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

Hope this solves your problem :)